# Spring threads interruption

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

I have a simple spring controller, which waits for some actions to be done. Let's say it looks like the following:

```
@GetMapping("/wait")
public void waitForFinish() throws InterruptedException {
    while (!allJobsAreFinished()) {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Now, for some reason, I want to interrupt this thread in a separate request. For this purpose, I save running thread to a map and in a separate method call `.interrupt()` on it:

```
private Map<String, Thread> runningThreads = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

@GetMapping("/wait")
public void waitForFinish() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
    runningThreads.put("testId", currentThread);
    //...
    runningThreads.remove("testId");
}

@GetMapping("/cancel")
public void cancel() {
    runningThreads.get("testId").interrupt();
}
```

My question is the following: is it a good idea to interrupt threads created by Spring? What can go wrong if I interrupt Spring thread? Or it is better to create `ExecutorService`, submit my tasks to it and interrupt them there via `Future`?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish in the /wait endpoint?

Comment: @jordiburgos it doesn't matter, this one is for example. There can be different long-running logic. `Wait` is the simplest example.

Comment: If you have long running logic's and if they are independent then use `CompletableFuture`, if you interrupt the web container thread client will get `500` response @DDovzhenko and it is not recommended to interrupt web container thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not interrupt threads that you don't know the consequences.

It could be done for threads that you created, you started, and you know what are the side effects.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking about, but I'm more interested in how Spring will behave if I interrupt his threads?

Comment: I don't think there's one unique behaviour in such circumstances. If you have transactions, they might be rolled back in the process... or not. If the state of the threads was preserved somewhere, those threads might start failing as well.

There is no reliable way to tell what Spring will do and such behaviour may change across versions. If you want to know for pure curiosity how Spring behaves... well... you'll have to try it out as the results might be tied to your own specific scenario.